# Different positioning in IE, Chrome, Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I'm working on this [Site](http://dh-creative-webdesign.de/rw-fliesen.html)

The position looks good in IE & Firefox, but in Chrome I have this

[image]

The code is too long to post it here thats why I insert the link files:

HTML: [link](http://pastebin.com/t07U2Zww)

CSS: [link](http://pastebin.com/KdRpcZEP)

What can we do to have the same outcome in all three browsers?

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem to a smaller HTML part and post that here with relevant CSS http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#leftcolumn .text2`, `#leftcolumn .text3` and `#leftcolumn .text4` each have a height of `10px` which is much smaller than the the height they would normally take up. Try removing these properties (lines 40, 41, 42), setting them to `auto` or setting a greater height and it should solve the issue.